# DropDownList with the non-unique values is screwing up viewstate/postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay, so I have a DropDownList control that contains 50 ListItems, one for each of the 50 states. The text value reflects each state name which makes each text value unique. However, the value property of each list item contains that state's current tax rate, which means that some of the values are not unique. Postbacks on this control constantly change the selected item. Is there a work around for this?

To duplicate, copy the code below into a new web form. It is just a simple DropDownList. Try selecting different states. Some of them stick, and others do not. For instance, try selecting "Idaho" as the state; it reverts to Arkansas for some reason. This is happening before the OnSelectedIndexChanged event even fires because if I select "Idaho" and then read the selected item in the event method on postback, the selected item is Arkansas! Very annoying.

```
            State:<br />
            <asp:DropDownList BorderWidth="3px" AutoPostBack="true" BackColor="#ffffcc" ID="ddlBillingState"
                runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Not Specified"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Alabama"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Alaska"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5.6" Text="Arizona"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Arkansas"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="8.25" Text="California"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2.9" Text="Colorado"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Connecticut"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="District of Columbia"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Delaware"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Florida"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Georgia"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Hawaii"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Idaho"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6.25" Text="Illinois"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Indiana"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Iowa"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5.3" Text="Kansas"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Kentucky"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Louisiana"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Maine"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Maryland"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6.25" Text="Massachusetts"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Michigan"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6.875" Text="Minnesota"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Mississippi"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4.225" Text="Missouri"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Montana"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5.5" Text="Nebraska"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6.85" Text="Nevada"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="New Hampshire"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="New Jersey"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="New Mexico"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="New York"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5.75" Text="North Carolina"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="North Dakota"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5.5" Text="Ohio"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4.5" Text="Oklahoma"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Oregon"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Pennsylvania"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Rhode Island"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="South Carolina"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="South Dakota"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Tennessee"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6.25" Text="Texas"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4.7" Text="Utah"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Vermont"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5.0" Text="Virginia"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6.5" Text="Washington"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="West Virginia"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Wisconsin"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Wyoming"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

I even tried disabling viewstate, then OnSelectedIndexChanged I would store the selected index in ViewState["selectedIndex"] and retrieve it on postback and repopulate the drop down list. But as I said before, because the selected item is a different value than the one intended before it even gets to the event, it was just storing the screwy value in my custom viewstate field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your values should be unique. Instead of putting the tax rate as the value, instead let the value simply be the state, and then use that state to obtain your tax value. As one example, in your code-behind, you could have a `Dictionary<string, decimal> taxTable` that you use to get your values. Such as

```
decimal taxRate = taxTable[yourDropDown.SelectedValue];
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was afraid of. Sucks when it boils down to something that's just not possible. I spent hours trying to find where the viewstate was being modified only to find out it had nothing to do with viewstate. lol

Comment: I am actually going the extra mile and building a tax database table. I should have done that in the first place for easy modification in the event of tax rate changes. This is what happens when you cut corners :P

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you get the Tax Rate from the State abbreviation or something?

In code behind:

```
decimal taxRate = GetTaxRateFromState(ddlState.SelectedValue);
```

I imagine the dropdown doesn't know which value is the one that was originally selected and it just sets the selected value to the first item that has the value that was POSTed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Chevex
Unfortunatelly there is no way to use a non-unique value for ListItem. You will have to generate a unique id for each tax rate and use the id as Value instead of tax rate

Answer (score 1):

Think of the "Value" as the primary key that ASP.NET uses to identify which item is selected from your DropDownList.  By repurposing the value attribute to store something else, the selected item (stored in ViewState by its value) is no longer unique, and cannot persist.  As others have mentioned, store your tax rate some place else, and use the selected state to determine the tax rate (outside of the DropDownList control itself).

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. You'd think that the ListItem would have a field called ID or something for that purpose, but oh well. I actually have two of these drop downs so it makes more sense to store the tax information in a database table anyway. That way both dropdowns can access the one source and the data could be modified with a tax updating tool in the future. That'll teach more for cutting corners! :P